# Unable to add mysql-connector to sqoop lib folder in AWS EMR cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, sqoop, mysql-connector

I am trying too run sqoop export in AWS EMR cluster. When I try to copy the MySQL connector jar to sqoop lib folder is gives me permission error:
`> cp mysql-connector-j-8.0.32/mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar /usr/lib/sqoop/lib

> cp: cannot create regular file ‘/usr/lib/sqoop/lib/mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar’: Permission denied`

I am expecting to add the connector jar to sqoop so I can run sqoop import or export.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo cp mysql-connector-j-8.0.32/mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar /usr/lib/sqoop/lib
```

You need to add "sudo" command in prefix to your command and enter the password (assuming you have sudo access) because /usr/lib path is restricted only for the root user.

If you do not have a sudo/admin privileges, then you need to contact your system administrator to perform the above copy command.